# Is there a benefit to using Encoded Polylines with Google Maps API v3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

If one is dealing with hundreds of polylines, would there be a big performance benefit to encoding the polylines using https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm?hl=sv-SE

It seems that this is mostly used with API v2 and v3 handles large amounts of polylines on its own fairly well?

I can't seem to find any benchmark comparisons.

Comment: I'm very surprised that this question is closed when actual factual numbers prove benefits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a substantial gain when using `google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath()` to decode encoded paths when adding a polyling/polygon to a google map.  I have a couple of paths with over a thousand points, and instead of looping through each point and creating a LatLng to be added to a Polygon, a simple decode loads visually quicker.

Additionally as Salman pointed out, there can be a substantial gain by reducing network traffic for passing paths via Ajax.  Take google's [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm):

```
Characters
0        1         2         3         4         5         6         7
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
38.5,-120.2|40.7,-120.95|43.252,-126.453  // Polyline Decoded: 40 chars
_p~iF~ps|U_ulLnnqC_mqNvxq`@               // Polyline Encoded: 27 chars
```

With only 3 points we've reduced the the size of the points by 33%.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is any formal benchmark. But encoded polylines become a lot smaller in size compared to actual lat/lng data. I've used it on occasions, specially when updating maps with Ajax.

Comment: So one would think the encoded polylines would be smaller but my test page with around 30 polylines has some interesting results. The uncompressed size of the page is smaller, but my server gzips the response and the gzip size of the unencoded version is actually smaller even though the uncompressed size is larger.


[encoded polylines]
size: 157KB
compressed: 32KB

[polylines]
size: 208KB
compressed: 31KB

Comment: What happens when you encode a huge number, say 3 million coordinates?